# Can't retrieve model with findOrFail(). IDE doesn't see this method. What is wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-controller

I have method in controller:

```
public function read(ReadRequest $request){

    $r  = $request;
    $id = $r->id;
    $order = null;

    try{
        $order= Order::firstOrFail($id);
    }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
        return response()->json(["message"=>"Order Id doesn't exist."], 404);
    }


    return response()->json(["order"=>$order], 200);

}
```

Order model is connected to controller file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

IDE says that it doesn't know firstOrFail() function. Controller method doesn't work when I'm trying to get data through XMLHttpRequest using Postmen. When I delete this part of code from method:

```
    try{
        $order= Order::firstOrFail($id);
    }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
        return response()->json(["message"=>"Order Id doesn't exist."], 404);
    }
```

Controller method starts to work. I think the problem is in firstOrFail() method, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you find by primary ID than use `findOrFail`

```
$order= Order::findOrFail($id);
```

If you find by another column than use `firstOrFail`

`$order = Order::where('column', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: Thank. I wonted to use findOrFail(). During other debugs I changed the name of the method to firstOrFail() and forget to replace it back. So, I have to rest)